# Two fields in one field

Tags: php

I am not experienced in PHP so I need your help on this. I would like to create on array from two, if I can say like that.
Basically, I would like to make from this:

> [{"Naziv":"Nemanja","duzina":"45.475","sirina":"23.423"},{"Naziv":"Aleksandar","duzina":"45.427","sirina":"21.124"}]

to something like this:

> [{"Naziv":"Nemanja","duzina":["45.475","23.423"]},{"Naziv":"Aleksandar","duzina":["45.427","21.124"]}]

Here is my PHP:

```
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

// query the application data

$sql = "SELECT Naziv,duzina,sirina FROM lokacije";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$rows[] = $row; 

}

// close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$rows[] = $row;
```

create a new array in your desired format:

```
$rows[] = array(
    'Naziv'  => $row['Naziv'],
    'duzina' => array($row['duzina'], $row['sirina'])
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ll accept your answer.